# Custom WPF binding not being updated on listbox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, dependencyobject

I'm puzzled by this probably trivial matter. I have my custom property on a descendant of `DevExpresses` class `LayoutGroup` (shouldn't make any difference IMO):

```
public class ExpandableLayoutGroup : LayoutGroup
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(Boolean), typeof(ExpandableLayoutGroup));

    public Boolean IsExpanded
    {
        get { return (Boolean) GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
        set
        {
            expandCheckBox.IsChecked = value;
            SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have XAML binding to a listbox (containing 2 items at this time) called `listStates`.

```
<ExpandableLayoutGroup x:Name="groupTool" IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedValue.IsTool, ElementName=listStates}" DataContext="{Binding Tool}" Header="Tool" View="GroupBox" />
```

The object list binding to listStates contains both properties (simplified):

```
public class State
{
    public Boolean IsItemTool { get; private set; }
    public Tool Tool { get; private set; }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Because I would expect that when I change listbox selection (single) it would also update `IsExpanded` property on a group. I have more subproperties of Tool binded (as apparent by `DataContext="{Binding Tool}"`) and those update well. So the `DataContext` is changing correctly on listbox selection. Except this one property `IsExpanded` (that should expand/collapse layoutgroup).

What am I doing wrong, and how to make it so, that when listbox changes, `IsExpanded` binding is polled to get value from `IsTool`, and will set it (depending on selection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters and setters of dependency properties must contain only `GetValue` and `SetValue` calls, because there're two ways to get and set their values: using getters and setters and using `DependencyProperty` or `DependencyPropertyKey`. This is why code in your setter is not executed (bindings don't use them for dependency properties). If you want some code to be executed when the value is changed, specify it as a `PropertyChangedCallback` callback in `PropertyMetadata`.

See [PropertyChangedCallback Delegate on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'll.. be.. damned. I had the callback set-up, but it was never called, because of other code in the property. Now it's really getting called. I never knew the property must be empty (except SetValue/GetValue). Now I know. Let me perform some tests, and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The setter for a dependency property must only set the value for it's underlying type. The .NET internals reserve the right to call `SetValue()` directly (and in my experience WPF usually does, while Silverlight uses the setter that you've defined).

Refer to the "Implications for Custom Dependency Properties" section of [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details

Comment: If this is confirmed, I'll accept Athari, but I will up vote you as well. You're quicker, but I understood the problem only after reading Athari's comment.